# How can I forward audio from the handset mic to wireless earbuds

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio, microphone

Im involved in a kind of cosplay where it's useful to have someone else relay verbal instructions from the sidelines. (Very heavy sound deadening helmet)

Because its in a small space, and I can't carry a handset, I can't set it up as say, a VOIP chat or call from their handset to mine.

So what I want is a way that I can pair some Bluetooth earbuds to a handset, and someone can talk into the handset mic, and it'll be relayed and played out on the bluetooth earbuds, which will fit discreetly under the cosplay. (I can modify the helmet to ensure space inside if needed).

Is that something Android can do natively, or does it need a visit to software recs stackexchange for an app to do it?

Comment: Did I miss the alternative of using both VOIP chat + wireless Bluetooth earbuds? Bluetooth can have range up to 10m, so you don't need to carry the handset with you.

Comment: I dont understand this comment (apart from the 10m range which is ample, hence the entire question of using BT to relay speech from handset mic to earbuds nearby). Can you expand this as an answer, if it is one? At thr moment its a rhetorical question hinting at VoIP but not actually "can it be done" and how...